# DevOps yaml pipeline define location

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I'm trying to add a submodule to my Azure DevOps yaml pipeline.

I Added the step to checkout the submodule.

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
```

The only side effect I'm having now is that it's moving the entire build repository to a subfolder (the name of the repository).

I'm trying to find out how to set the root back to the build directory back again. I tried setting the `path` below the submodule in the checkout step. I just can't seem to find where I need to set this paramter and how it's called.

I was reading about the variables over here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

I was reading about the azure git repos over here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

None of these resources say how to fix this.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a `path` is specified for a `checkout` step, that path is used, relative to `(Agent.BuildDirectory)`.

If you are using default paths, adding a second repository `checkout` step changes the default path of the code for the first repository. For example, the code for a repository named `tools` would be checked out to `C:\agent\_work\1\s` when tools is the only repository, but if a second repository is added, `tools` would then be checked out to `C:\agent\_work\1\s\tools`. If you have any steps that depend on the source code being in the original location, those steps must be updated.

See: [Checkout path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path) and [Checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) for more details. Please check it and kindly let me know the result.